# Increment challenge: ++ vs. +1

Tags: c++, performance, caching, optimization

I was practicing with exercises on caches when I got stucked and I started wondering about differences between a unary increment ++ and the +1 operation.

I have this line of code(let's call it **CODE1**):

```
h[img.getVal(x,y)]++;
```

Is this the same of coding the following?(let's call it **CODE2**)

```
h[img.getVal(x,y)]=h[img.getVal(x,y)]+1;
```

It is obvious that they are the same, speaking about the macroscopic effect(they both increment by 1 `h[img.getVal(x,y)]`), but, are they really the same?
I am wondering this because of caches.

Let's say we have a direct-mapped cache and that the first `pixel(0,0)` is allocated in RAM at address `0xA0000000`, while the first `h[0]` at `0xB0000000`.
Assuming a 6-bit offset, 10-bit index, and 16-bit tag, we have this situation:

`0xA0000000` in binary is:

```
--------TAG---------|---INDEX----|-OFFSET
1010 0000 0000 0000 |0000 0000 00|00 0000
```

as well as `0xB0000000` in binary is:

```
--------TAG---------|---INDEX----|-OFFSET
1011 0000 0000 0000 |0000 0000 00|00 0000
```

How many misses and hits(**AND WHY**) are there using the 2 codes, **assuming that we are accessing pixel(0,0), so x=0, y=0, and that pixel(0,0) has a value of 0**(it's black, this is a grayscale image)? Are there differences using those 2 different codes?

I would say there are at least 2 misses, because, in both cases, first the program has to do `img.getVal(x,y)`, which results in a miss, fills a line in the cache and returns the value 0 to the CPU, and then `h[img.getVal(x,y)]` which returns a miss as well, because the cache does not contain any information related to the h array yet.
But then, what happens?
We now have in cache the value of `h[0]` and we need to increment it. I think there are differences here using the 2 codes above.

Cheers,

Marco

**EDIT:** This is not referred to any particular compiler. I am wondering how this works. (The exercise is on paper)

Comment: Both lines violate my coding standard. Code 1, for sure: Never, ever mix ++ or -- with [] evaluations. Code 2, probably: separate it into two lines, to enhance readability; one with "h[img.getVal(x,y)]+1" and the other with the assignment.

Comment: It seems you are thinking at the wrong level of abstraction. Did you give the compiler enough information that it knows it does not need to call `getVal` twice in CODE2? If you did, there is no reason a compiler should not generate the same code for CODE1 and CODE2. If you didn't, then the latter half of your question is redundant. CODE2 is less efficient because it calls `getVal` twice.

Comment: @chris which one does not modify the variable?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying, but the second will call getVal twice and index the array twice, so I would expect it to be slower. If getVal is inline function with simple logic that will return the same value for the same parameters, and h is an ordinary array, maybe the compiler could optimize that.

Comment: @MarcoGalassi, My bad, I only read the `var + 1` part, not the assignment.

Comment: Mats is right. I would say `{int& hh = h[blahblah]; hh++;}`. That way, you're keeping your intentions clear and not counting on the compiler's dubious IQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two code snippets should be identical if we assume that `img.getVal(x,y)` returns the same value every time. Which of course, without knowing exactly how `img.getVal(x,y)` is implemented, we can't say.

As to how many hits and misses this line of code generates will be entirely dependent on what the state of the cache is at the entry of the code, and if the code gets interrupted, etc, etc. But one would assume, if this line is run in isolation, with empty caches and no interrupts, that it's one miss (for the read operation) and one hit (for the write back of the updated value). But that doesn't take into account wnatever `img.getVal(x,y)` does - which I don't know, since you don't show that code.

Comment: Think about img.getVal(x,y) as a single instruction. It retrives the value of the pixel at (x,y).

How can it be 1 miss and 1 hit?
The first img.getVal(x,y) is a miss, and then h[thevaluejustreturned] is another miss too. No?

Comment: Exactly what are you counting? The update of `h[whatever]` will have a miss for the read (because it's not yet in the cache) and a hit when it writes the value back. And if the pixel at (x,y) is not in cache, then that will be a miss too - since graphics memory is often uncacheable, and if `getImg(x,y)` isn't optimised out because the compiler doesn't figure out that it returns a constant value for a given `x,y`, you may have a second miss in the second option. And finally, you may also have code-cache misses (or hits). You have to define what memory operations the compiler generates...

Comment: @MarcoGalassi An optimizing compiler does not work the way you think it works. It does not have to to generate one assembly instruction for each and every source-level construct. It generates an assembly program that is equivalent to the source code for some definition of equivalent. If you give it enough information to infer that `h[img.getVal(x,y)]=h[img.getVal(x,y)]+1;` and `h[img.getVal(x,y)]++;` are the same, it will generate the same code for both.